# Pronunciation of 'Iran'

Tags: pronunciation

Lexico [says](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/iran) the first syllable of 'Iran' can only be pronounced as [ɪ], but I constantly hear it pronounced as [aɪ] and Wiktionary lists it as an option (yes, I understand everything about the credibility of Wiktionary). Can I pronounce the first syllable as [aɪ]?

Comment: The first is more AmE.

Comment: Notice that there is not necessarily a “right way” (or maybe two “right ways”) to pronounce the names of foreign countries, etc in English. People may claim that the “right way” is the way that conforms to the way it is pronounced in the city/country/language of its origin and yet others use the widely accepted pronunciation in the English language context. Examples: is Paris pronounced more like “Par-ee” or is it pronounced to rhyme with ”Harris”?  Is the capital of Russia “Moss-co” or “Moss-cow”?  Is Kiribati pronounced “Kiri-Barty” or “Kiri-Bus”?

Comment: There is another point of pronunciation here too. There seems to be some contention in English around both syllables of “Iran”. The last syllable “-an” can be pronounced like the English name “Anne” or like the “un” in “until”. So you can hear: “Eye-ran”, “Eye-run”, “Ee-run” and “Ee-ran”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to a couple of well-known online dictionaries [[1](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/iran), [2](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/iran?q=Iran), [3](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/Iran), [4](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/iran)], *Iran* is most often pronounced in these two ways, in American English (AmE) as well as in British English (BrE):

1. `/ɪˈrɑːn/` (ih-rahn)
2. `/ɪˈræn/` (ih-ran)

If you follow [this link](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/iran?q=Iran) to a dictionary entry above, you'll be able to hear the word pronounced by clicking on the little speaker icons next to the transcriptions.

There is another, variant pronunciation that occurs in AmE dialects:

3. `/aɪˈræn/` (eye-ran)

This pronunciation is listed in the [Merriam-Webster.com dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Iran) (MW) and the [American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=Iran) (AHD) as the third alternative, although it's not clear from that alone how prevalent / acceptable / (in)formal that particular variant is in AmE. [MW's FAQ](https://www.merriam-webster.com/help/faq-audio-pronunciations) says "where there are multiple variant pronunciations only the first, most common variant is offered in audio format", which would mean only the first pronunciation here is the most common, with the third one presumably being the least common.

Luckily, the AHD entry for *Iran* contains the following Usage Note (the number of the corresponding transcription above is denoted in curly braces immediately after the AHD's phonetic notation):

> ***Usage Note***: As foreign locales become more familiar to English speakers, the pronunciation of their names often evolves away from a literal rendering of their English spelling and toward their native pronunciation, though with considerable variation across names and speakers. *Prague* once rhymed with *plague* but now is closer to *bog*, while *Chile* may be pronounced either as "chilly" or "chee-lay," and *Brazil* is still Anglicized (brə-zĭl') rather than Portuguese (brä-sēl'). In American English today, we find three common pronunciations for *Iran*: (ĭ-rän' {1}, ĭ-răn' {2}, and ī-răn' {3}), with analogous variants for *Iraq*. In our 2014 Usage Ballot, most Panelists personally preferred (ĭ-rän' {1}), but a large majority considered both (ĭ-rän' {1}) and (ĭ-răn' {2}) acceptable. The same was true for *Iraq*. Panelists were much less tolerant of the pronunciation of the initial syllable as "eye" {3} (some commented that this pronunciation seemed "unsophisticated" or "parochial"): 71% deemed (ī-răn' {3}) unacceptable, with only 6% reporting it as their preferred pronunciation, with similar percentages for *Iraq*.

---

Therefore, if we assume that the results of the AHD's Usage Ballot survey are reliable, you can use the third pronunciation listed above if you're trying to emulate speech that most people find unacceptable in AmE.

In my experience (I'm not a native speaker of English), that pronunciation is indeed looked upon with disfavor.